# vector-valued forms of a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\omega:M\rightarrow\Lambda^qT^*M\otimes E$ is a vector-valued $q$-form we have $\omega(p):\Lambda^q T^*M\otimes E\rightarrow E$ for each $p\in M$.

So we can identifies these vector-valued $q$-forms with alternanting multilinear map from $\Lambda^q TM$ to $E$ in this way:
if $\omega:M\rightarrow\Lambda^qT^*M\otimes E$ is a vector-valued form like above we can define a map from $\Lambda^q TM$ to $E$ as $\overline{w}:\Lambda^q TM\rightarrow E$, $(X_1,...,X_q)\mapsto \omega_p(X_1,...,Xq,v)$ where $\omega_p\otimes v$ is $\omega(p)$. Viceversa, if $\overline{w}:\Lambda^q TM\rightarrow E$ is an alternanting multilinear map we can define $\omega:M\rightarrow\Lambda^qT^*M\otimes E$ in this way: $\omega(p)(X_1,...,X_q):=\overline{\omega}(X_1,...,X_q)$.

It's right? First of all.

Now, i want repeat this argument in the case where $E=T^{1,0}M$ and the $q$-forms are $q$-forms of type ${0,1}$.

What do you think? It's reasonable?

Comment: If $p\in M$, then $\omega(p) \in T^*M \otimes E$, which means that as a function, $\omega(p) \colon TM \to E$, which is why we call it a "$E$-valued $1$-form': it sends vectors of $TM$ to elements of $E$. Similarly, a $E$-valued $q$-form gives birth to alternate $q$-linear functions $\omega(p) \colon T_pM\times \cdots \times T_pM \to E$.

Comment: Yes, but i ask if my argument is right formally. I guess yuo agree with me, thanks u.